# Add-in Ribbon creation in MS office excel using java

Tags: c#, java, swing, excel, ms-office

I am a freelancer and very new to C#(comfortable in Java). In my new project I need to create a ribbon in excel sheet and work around that.

Can I create the ribbon in excel using Java as I am not comfortable with C#? I googled and found no answers about it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My only recommendation is plough on with C#, I've heard it is *very, very* similar to Java, and worth learning.